# How to send false/true value using json using Ruby ( for jQuery validation )?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I have such problem: I'm checking user email and can't tell validator that value is valid or not.

I have such action:

```
def checkemail
 respond_to do |format|
 format.jsonr do
  if User.where(email: params[:email]).exists? 
    render :json => {
        :status  => :false,
        }.to_json
   else
     render :json => {
        :status  => :true,
        }.to_json
     end
    end
  end
end
```

here is jQuery:

```
    $(".sign_up").validate({
    rules: {
         "user[email]": {
          remote: {
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/checkemail.jsonr",
            type: "get",
            data: {
              email: function() { return $("#email").val(); }
            }
          }
        }
    })
```

Here is result from console:

```
    Processing by EditUserController#checkemail as JSONR
    Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"use@mail.com"}, "email"=>"use@mail.com"}
    ←[1m←[36mUser Exists (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 
   'use@mail.com' LIMIT 1←[0m
```

So the validation isn't passing, but should.

Also tried to pass page status code, but failed.

Can someone suggest where is my error ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting these properties:

```
remote: {
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
  dataType: "json",
  ...
```

Comment: thanks, didn't help. maybe I need something change in my action ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use false/true booleans instead of :false/:true

```
puts({:status => :false}.to_json)
{"status":"false"}
```

vs

```
puts({:status => false}.to_json)
{"status":false}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError (C:/3108/1209/app/controllers/edit_user_controller.rb:24: syntax err
or, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
      {"status":"false"}
                ^`

Comment: We can talk in Ukrainian, dude)